# Modify Code From Delete to Clear Contents - Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below code that I would like to change from deleting to clear Contents

```
function DeleteAnytrue() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();

var rowsDeleted = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if (row[2] == true) {

// tried adding this line below but no luck
sheet.clearContents((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);

//sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
rowsDeleted++;
}
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to clear the rows when the column "C" is `true` using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- About `sheet.clearContents((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);`, unfortunately, the method of `clearContents()` of Class Sheet has no arguments and in this case, all cell values are cleared.
- In your situation, I would like to propose to use the method of `clearContent()` of Class RangeList. When this method is used, it can be used outside of the loop.
- In this modification, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Search rows which have `true` in the column "C" using TextFinder and create an array including A1Notations.
  2. Clear the cell values using `clearContent()` of Class RangeList.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function DeleteAnytrue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // 1. Search rows which have `true` in the column "C" using TextFinder and create an array including A1Notations.
  var a1Notations = sheet
    .getRange("C1:C" + sheet.getLastRow())
    .createTextFinder("TRUE")
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findAll()
    .map(r => {
      var row = r.getRow();
      return `A${row}:${row}`
    });
  
  // 2. Clear the cell values using `clearContent()` of Class RangeList.
  if (a1Notations.length > 0) sheet.getRangeList(a1Notations).clearContent();
}
```

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [clearContents() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clearcontents)
- [clearContent() of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#clearContent())

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike Code worked as expected

Comment: @DUBYA RX Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function DeleteAnytrue() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i)=> { 
    if (r[2] == true) {
      sh.getRange(i+1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent()
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [textFinder.replaceWith()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#replaceWith(String)) function with `replaceText` as `""`.

The documentation for text finders can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder).